# For sys. admins, are you legally required to surrender your passwords if you leave your job?

Tags: password

Just a quick question for you guys, and I have been wondering about it ever since. I know that I am legally required to reset them to whatever the company wants them to, but what if my boss asks me for my personal AD account password (which is going to be disabled anyway). I don't think I am legally required to surrender MY password. I think I am only legally forced to reset it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you are asking for legal advice on a technical website. Consult a local lawyer.

Comment: Why does it matter? You're not reusing the same password in more than one place are you?

Comment: And even if hypothetically you're not legally required to hand it over, he can still fire you if you don't. Although from context it sounds like you're kindof expecting that to happen anyway...  And I agree with @EEAA that the question is totally off topic.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should do whatever your company policy dictates. In the absence of anything else, no, you're not legally required to do anything once you've left a position.